# An inequality of operator norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I 'm proving $$
\max \left(\|A\|^{2},\|B\|^{2}\right) \leq\|T\|^{2} \leq\|A\|^{2}+\|B\|^{2}
$$ where $
T=A+i B
$ is cartesian decomposition of T. Since $\|Tx\|^{2}= \|Ax\|^{2} + \|Bx\|^{2}$,I'm wondering whether this 
$$
\max \left(\|A\|^{2},\|B\|^{2}\right) \leq \frac{\|Ax\|^{2} + \|Bx\|^{2}}{\|x\|^2}
$$
is true.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Surely false if your inequality is supposed to be for  each fixed $x$. We can have $Ax=0=Bx$ without $A$ and $B$ being zero.

However the inequality is true if you have sup over all non-zero $x$ on RHS.